# 'Obtener detalles' en tarjeta de Power BI

Tags: powerbi

[image: Botón obtener detalles]

Buen día! Les quería consultar si hay alguna forma de poder acceder a la opción de "Obtener detalles" de Power BI a través de una tarjeta. Lo logré con una matriz de 1x1, lo cual me trae otros dolores de cabeza en el reporte y prefería poder usar tarjeta o algún objeto visual similar. Este obtener detalles lo uso para ir a otra página del reporte donde muestra la información filtrada a partir de los datos de la matriz 1x1. Desde ya gracias!

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado? ¿Qué errores tienes? Recuerda el [Ejemplo Mínimo Verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) de lo que has hecho y fundamentalmente parte del código que has utilizado (en texto, no imagen) que se menciona en el [tour] y en [ask].